# text, usetex=true setting renders the axis labels as well

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

I tried rendering some TeX in a figure today but it didn't work. I realized, `text.usetex` in the matplotlibrc file was set to `False`.
When I add `rc('text', usetex=True)` to my script, the axis labels are rendered as TeX as well which is undesirable.
I don't remember ever having to set this before matplotlib 1.3.0 and I definitely don't remember any difficulty rendering TeX.

Anyone else experiencing this behavior?

Example:

```
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects

# matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,0.9,1])
ax.imshow(randn(20,20))
txt = ax.text(0.1, 0.5, r"Some \LaTeX\ $\alpha=\beta$", transform=ax.transAxes,fontsize=16)
txt.set_path_effects([PathEffects.Stroke(linewidth=3, foreground="w"), PathEffects.Normal()])
```

Produces:

[image]

Uncommenting the `matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)' line, produces:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your 'question' isn't really a question, but I am assuming you are having the following issue:

You want to add some text to the plot using either a latex font, or just to add maths without using `rc('text', usetex=True)` (note that in the default rcparams file it states that this affects *all* text).

This can be done:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig = plt.figure()
plt.annotate(r"$\mathcal{G}r \epsilon \epsilon \kappa$", xy=(5, 2), size=26)
plt.annotate(r"default font", xy=(2, 5), size=16)
plt.annotate(r"latex font", xy=(2, 7), size=20, family='computer modern roman')
plt.plot(range(10))
plt.xlabel("some string")
```

[image]

Hope that helps somewhat!

Comment: Hi Greg, I guess I wasn't clear enough: TeX is not being rendered unless `usetex=True`

Comment: I added an example to my original question to explain the problem.

Comment: I see your issue now, indeed I don't think matplotlib will support the behaviour you want at the moment. Ideally an arg `usetex=True` passed into `ax.text(...)` is what you want. Perhaps raise the issue on github?